# Daisy chain programming with PIC Microcontrollers

Tags: pic

Is it possible to program multiple PIC microcontrollers using only 1 PICKit2 programmer? The microcontrollers is connected via daisy chain. With PGC, PGD and MCLR of the PIC to be programmed is connected to the GPIO of the programming PIC.

Answer (score 1):

I may be wrong, but I do not think this will work well as MPLBX will want to read back the written data to verify the programming operation succeed.

Alternatively, have you considered using PICkit3's in their "independent of a computer" mode?  The PICKit3's can be configured to burn a specific program into a target PIC independent of a computer.  I am wondering if having an "army" of these might address your issues.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe so. Just for fun after finding this question I took two 12f508's that were known to be good.

To prove that they were good I used IPE to load a previously tested program onto two devices. The devices worked as expected. I then used IPEs "fill memory" tool to program both devices to all empty (every address has 0x00), less the oscillator calibration memory location (I've had trouble with this area in the pass, so I always disable reading and writing to that location).

I then connected both chips up to the programmer in parallel and tried to program them with the same program. This is where everything went horribly awry.

For some reason, the programmer got confused and wrote a value of 0xFF to all addresses, including the out of range addresses. I verified that this was what actually happened by disconnecting the chips from the circuit and reading them independently.

Luckily for me I ran into this problem repeatedly before, and so have built a programmer out of an arduino and some extra circuits, so that I can ignore the stupid "oscillator calibration data invalid" error and reprogram that location to the correct instruction. It takes a long time to read and write memory, but it saves otherwise bricked chips.

---

In shorter words: No, this does not work, and it may actually "brick" your chips.